# Safari 6 breaking Rails collection routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, safari

I have the following code in my routes.rb file:

```
resources :wbs_nos, except: [:new, :create] do
  collection { get 'wbs_tpr_filtered' }
end

resources :task_plan_requests do
  resources :wbs_nos, only: [:new, :create]

  collection do
    get :auto_complete_for_wbs_number_wbs_number
    get :auto_complete_for_task_plan_request_fabrication_work_order_number
    get :auto_complete_for_task_plan_request_requestor_building
    get :auto_complete_for_task_plan_request_requestor_name
    get :auto_complete_for_task_plan_request_requestor_email
  end
end
```

In Chrome when I go to localhost:3000/wbs_nos/wbs_tpr_filtered the request is correctly sent to the was_tpr_filtered action in the WbsNosController.

In Safari 6 it is sending me to the show action in the WbsNosController and rails gives the error:

> Couldn't find WbsNo with id=wbs_tpr_filtered.

I get the folling when I run rake routes:

```
wbs_tpr_filtered_wbs_nos GET /wbs_nos/wbs_tpr_filtered(.:format)  wbs_nos#wbs_tpr_filtered
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just for safety, have you tried this on Firefox or Opera? And have you tried deleting browser cache?

Comment: Yeah I tried them all.  Clearing the cache as mentioned below fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind Safari cached the page when "Couldn't find WbsNo with id=wbs_tpr_filtered" was a valid error.  Removing the folder Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari fixed the issue.